# How to crop video using Android SDK or NDK method

Tags: android, video, android-ndk

I have a very wide video that I am trying to crop a part of in the display and I was trying to find a method of perhaps taking a bitmap of the native resolution of that video and then doing what I like with that (i.e. move the video from side to side). I want to be able to watch the resized images placed on the screen as if the video is cropped. I imagine this would be done with something like [getDrawingCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache%28%29) but I'm not getting the full resolution I'm looking for. Does anyone know a way around this?

Edit: I have found the latest [source file](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java) for the videoview so I am going to see how well editing that will work

Answer (score 0):

You can simply render the video on a surface larger than the actual display, and then manipulate the position and cropping of this view.

Comment: Thanks - but hat doesn't seem to work because the video view always resizes to the full width of the page. I tried something like this and it just doesn't resize the way you'd hope, I've found.

Comment: You should customize the video view to change this "resize" behavior.

Comment: I'll have a look into this, cheers - it sounds like you've been through this yourself with some success then. Time to have another go!

Comment: I'll post the fix once I've dabbled in it